# Error install new module by "install extension wizard" button in DNN7

Tags: dotnetnuke

I have a module which can be installed in DNN 5(5.6.X), everything OK on that version.
When I try to install the exactly same module onto DSS7(7.0.1), by the button "install extension wizard" on the "find more module" page.
After I choose the module then click next, I got a error:
**A critical error has occurred.The ReadElementContentAsString method is not supported on node type Comment. Line 5, position 7.**

Could you tell me the possible reason about it?

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that you have an old .DNN manifest file, and maybe DNN7 doesn't like that. Can you post a copy of the .DNN file in your question?